# Strategies to encrypt on Azure without using KeyVault

Tags: azure, encryption, storage, azure-storage

Need to store some content in Azure Blob Storage, and want to encrypt prior to storing it on Azure Blob (we don't want to rely on Azure storage encryption on-rest). The issue is we do not want to store our encryption keys on Azure (e.g. Key vault), and store it outside of Azure. Any suggestion on strategies for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue is we do not want to store our encryption keys on Azure (e.g. Key vault), and store it outside of Azure.

Azure Storage Service Encryption doesn’t allow us to use our own encryption keys until now.  To use your own encryption keys and store it outside of Azure, you need to create a proxy for your storage service.

For example, you could create a Web API to handle all the blob read/write  requests. In your Web API, you could use your own encryption keys to encrypt or decrypt data and then write or read the data to Azure Blob Storage.

The limit of this way is that we can’t use the Azure Storage Client library or other tools to access the storage proxy (Web API) since it is written by yourself.

> Any suggestion of on-premise secret options we can use, which are accessible to components on Azure.

I suggest you store the key on your local side and create a internal API which could return this key. To access this internal API from azure components, you could use hybrid connections.

[Access on-premises resources using hybrid connections in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started)

Comment: Thanks Amor. Actually I was looking for ways to store encryption keys outside of Azure (on-premise). Any suggestion of on-premise secret options we can use, which are accessible to components on Azure.